# Tagging [identify-this-game] with the identified games tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, game-identification

I was thinking should we add the game title tag to *successfully answered* [identify-this-game](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/identify-this-game) tagged questions?

For example, I would add [outland](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outland) to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30588/platformer-blue-and-red-mechanic, and [shadow-hearts](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/shadow-hearts) to https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/30443/searching-for-a-ps2-game-set-in-the-early-1900s.